# WPF : Override numeric and currency format to get rid of converter

Tags: .net, wpf, string-formatting

Here is the deal.

I have a datagrid (actually a telerik rad grid, but I don't think it makes much difference), in which we have many currency columns (close to 10) that we want to format in a very specif manner (i.e. not the typical $0.00 format we usually). In order to do that, we use a converter, which works perfectly fine. However, two problems arises

- All columns with such format needs a long definition (Converter={static... with a parameter, so that we only have one converter.
- I feel like the use of converter slows down the grid rendering by quite a lot.

We tried to input the actual format in the grid but the result is not always the same then if you use a converter. For exemple, if we put "#,0.00" (2 decimal and a thousand separator), we get 10,000.00 if the string format is in the grid instead of 10 000.00 (our thousand separator in a space here). This is actually why we started using converter in the first place.

I was thinking, is there any way to create or override a string format. For exemple

```
{Binding Price, StringFormat='c2'}
```

which stands for currency with 2 decimals. Could we somehow change it so that it will works exactly how we want ? This should remove the need of converter and most likely speed up the rendering.

Thanks.

Comment: telerik Label and TextBlock support format string flexibly,you should take advantage of those controls by using column template instead of bindind directly

Answer (score 0):

You can't change how the `StringFormat` is applied apart from changing the culture that is used when the `ToString()` method is called on the value to be formatted.

You could set the `DataFormatString` property of the column: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/data-formatting

Or you could return an already formatted value from the view model and perform any conversion logic directly in this class instead of using a converter:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedValue}" ... />
```

Comment: I tried DataFormatString and I get the same problem. I will ask support for help and post the answer.

Comment: I have already listed the options you have. Maybe you should consider trying my suggestion of returning an already formatted value form the source property...?

Comment: What about the option "apart from changing the culture that is used when the ToString() method is called on the value to be formatted" ? How do we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, only thing missing was this :

IsLocalizationLanguageRespected="false"